# Como Alterar Idioma Padrão de Mensagem de Validação de Uma Aplicação ASP. NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web, web.config, internacionalização

Tenho um modelo assim:

```
[Display(Name = "Protocolos Abertos")]
public int ProtocolosId { get; set; }
```

que utilizo em um SelectList como o `value`, quando vou fazer o submit de um formulário a mensagem de validação é retornada em idiomas diferentes para localhost e para o servidor de homologação.

**- Servidor de Teste:**
[image: Servidor de teste]

**- Localhost:**
[image: Localhost]

a `web.config` está configurada:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
```

Existe alguma outra configuração na aplicação a ser realizada para efetuar essa alteração de inglês para português?

**OBS:**
 Sei que é possível criar mensagens de erro customizadas para os campos, porém a mensagem padrão é bem útil.

Comment: Essa validação é a do backend ou do frontend?

Comment: Acredito que seja no frontend, pois nem chega no método para tratar o post.

Comment: Utilizo `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProtocolId, Model.ProtocolsList,"Selecione um protocolo", new { @id = "ProtocolId" })` quando está em "Selecione um protocolo" não há nenhum valor em `ProtocolId`, o que ocasiona essa mensagem, pois o mesmo é do tipo `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei para o problema foi instalar o [language package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14236/language-packs) correspondente ao idioma desejado direto no servidor.
Após isso as mensagens de validação começaram a aparecer no idioma correto.